# How to get all html tags in order from html string in Java

Tags: java, regex, html-parsing, jsoup

```
<td valign="top" width="230">
<div>
<b><a href="http://www.cs.cornell.edu/johannes/">Johannes Gehrke</a></b>
</div>
<div class="small">
Professor<br>Computer Science, CS Field Member<br>Director of Graduate Studies<br>
Ph.D., Univ of Wisconsin, Madison, 1999<br><b>Research focus:</b> Database systems, data mining, and data privacy
</div>
</td>
```

I'd like to get the tag sequence from given html string. What's the easiest way to do it? For example, taking the above html string as input, I'd like my method to output an array of Strings, i.e.,`[td,div,b,a,div,br,br,br,br,b]`.

I've tried `Jsoup` to parse the html string, but there seems no way to capture tags like `br`. I wonder any other Java libs can do the trick for me. The last resort would be using the regex technique. If someone can come up with a neat regular expression for that purpose, it will do as well.

Comment: You can try any DOM-based xml library.

Comment: Maybe regex can not be best option: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/706695

Comment: you should try out with documentStream builder which is bind entire DOM.

Comment: @svz xml library?u need an html parser...xml and html are very different

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ, in which way, other than HTML is a *not well-formed* xml, are they different?

Comment: @svz `xml` is strict with its format but `html` is not..you **cant** use xml api's to parse html

Comment: @HRgiger for my problem, regex seems the best option because otherwise I need to parse the html string and recurse over it to find the tag sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<([^\\s>/]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    while(m.find()) {
        String tag = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(tag);
    }
```

Comment: You can't parse HTML with Regexes. HTML is not a regular language, so there is no Regex that can parse any HTML string correctly.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Once you have parsed the string with JSoup, use its [getAllElements()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getAllElements%28%29) method, iterate on the result, and for every element, call [tagName()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#tagName%28%29).

Comment: JSoup will try generate also all valid tags until `<td>` in his example, returning also `html`, `head`, `body`, `table` and `tr` which he OP don't want

Comment: br tag is being included as well? and is parsing really necessary?

Comment: Yes, the br tag is included, I just tested it. Regarding the unwanted tags, JSoup removed the td altogether, and places the div directly under the body element.

Comment: If he knows that it will always be starting from a `td` then he can use the select criteria `tr *`. But it's gross

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using an `HTMLEditorKit.Parser`.  Even though Swing can only render HTML 3.2, the parser should read and preserve all tags:

```
public List<String> getTags(Reader reader)
throws IOException {

    final List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback callback =
        new HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void handleStartTag(HTML.Tag tag,
                                       MutableAttributeSet attributes,
                                       int pos) {
                super.handleStartTag(tag, attributes, pos);
                tags.add(tag.toString());
            }
        };

    HTMLEditorKit.Parser parser = new ParserDelegator();
    parser.parse(reader, callback, true);

    return tags;
}
```